# Display dates from a last week Friday to before Last week of Friday in Oracle/PLSQL

Tags: oracle

I want to display dates from dates column, the condition is - It should display dates only between last week Friday to before last week Friday in oracle PL/SQL

I have got the below code but its not working.Please let me know what needs to fixed.

```
SELECT Dates FROM tablename where dates BETWEEN TRUNC(Dates,'d')-2 AND TRUNC(Dates,'d')-9;
```

**Example -**

Dates Column has dates from 2016 to 2018, Example -

```
Table1 :
Dates
02/12/2016
04/07/2017
04/01/2018
09/03/2018
10/03/2017
12/03/2016
15/03/2018
```

When I run the query - It should display dates which falls between a week before Friday to Last week Friday. That is - A week before Friday date was 9th March 2018 and last week Friday was 16th March 2018.

Now when i run the query It should display dates which are between 9th March 2018(Friday) till 16th March 2018(Friday).

```
Required Output Table:-

Dates
09/03/2018
15/03/2018
```

Please let me know if you need additional information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An example of the expected output would help.

Comment: Please read this: [Tips for sql questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056) and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: The query exactly as you wrote it has no chance of producing any output. You are asking the value `dates` to be between 2 and 9 days before **itself**, you are not comparing `dates` to the **current** date (as returned for example by `sysdate`).

Comment: Result of `TRUNC(...,'d')` depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY` settings. Use `TRUNC(...,'IW')` or `WHERE TO_CHAR(...,'fmDy', 'NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = American') = 'Fri'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how you define "week", but perhaps the hints below will help.

In a large part of the world, a week begins on Monday and it ends on Sunday. It is so common, it is the "ISO week" (the "standard week" in technology). In particular, given a date - like today's date, SYSDATE - the function

```
trunc(...., 'iw')
```

will return the Monday of the ISO week containing the date.

NEXT_DAY(...., 'Fri') returns the first Friday following the first argument. So that you don't get "a week later" if you run this on Friday (or on Saturday), you can use the `TRUNC` function as shown above.

This will give you the Friday of the current week. To subtract a week, or two, you can subtract 7 or 14.

Your WHERE condition might look something like

```
where dates between next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'iw'), 'Friday') - 14
                and next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'iw'), 'Friday') -  7
```

**Caution**:

You may be tempted to simplify this to

```
where next_day(trunc(sysdate, 'iw'), 'Friday') - dates between 7 and 14
```

and mathematically that is correct (trivial algebra). DON'T DO THAT!

If you write the WHERE clause the way I wrote it the first time, if you have an index on `dates` (as you should, if you have many queries which select data in certain date intervals), the optimizer will be able to use the index.

If you are too clever and you re-write the `where` clause using algebra, as I showed, your code will be shorter - but the optimizer will no longer use the index. The optimizer isn't smart enough to "see" that it can isolate `dates` on one side of the inequality so it could use the index; the optimizer doesn't know any algebra, not even fifth grade level.